# RDRAND intrinsics on apple silicon - How to generate a random number in c++?

Tags: c++, random, apple-m1, arm64

How would you create a random number based on RDRAND ARM64 intrinsics on apple silicon (M1+) ?

Since arm-v8.5-A RDRAND is supported, but how can you use it on a m1 machine?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device probably does the right thing

Comment: _rdrand64_step could be translated to std::random_device ?

Comment: No, probably not directly, but I'd hope that `std::random_device` will call some os random number generation api which will call `RDRAND` underneath

Comment: https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpps-random_device.html

Answer (score 3):

> Since arm-v8.5-A RDRAND is supported, [...].

No, and no.
`RDRAND` is an Intel thing. ARMv8.5-A introduces `FEAT_RNG`, but that is *optional*. The `ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1.RNDR` field says that both M1 and M2 generations of Apple Silicon Macs do *not* implement this feature.
Also note that M1 is only ARMv8.4-A compliant, not ARMv8.5-A. I've been told you're allowed to cherry-pick features from one minor version above the one you're supporting, but that does not make M1 ARMv8.5-A compliant. M2, on the other hand, does appear to be ARMv8.5-A compliant.

Now, if you're targeting something that *does* support `FEAT_RNG` and you're using clang, then you can use the following two builtins:

```c
int __builtin_arm_rndr(uint64_t *val);
int __builtin_arm_rndrrs(uint64_t *val);
```

These functions (in their current implementation) return `1` on failure and `0` on success, and if successful, store a random value at the address pointer to by `val`.

You can compile the following test binary with `clang -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +rand` (it's C, but it works the same way in C++):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t u = 0;
    int r = __builtin_arm_rndr(&u);
    printf("%d, 0x%016llx\n", r, u);
    return 0;
}
```

It just won't run on M1 or M2 hardware.

As for the *supported* ways of getting random numbers:

- The platform-specific way would be to read from `/dev/random`.
- The C++-specific way would be [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).

Comment: thanks. on my m1 the above code returns: "illegal hardware instruction" . So as you said it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
\* try -seems to work?? *\
float
CU_rand(void)
{
    float current_random;
 #ifdef M1RANDOM
    float power = 1LL << 31;
    float maxrand;
    maxrand = power-1;
    current_random = random()/maxrand;
/*
    printf(" max floating random no %f\n",maxrand);
*/
#endif
return current_random;
}

(with prototypes etc)
```